# How to create a relationship on the field of a model with three different models in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Just a fool question I have a model `Exam` which contains a field `Subject` which I want to connect with 3 or 4 or even 5 subjects like foreign key connect one with it.

```
# 1 type
class Math(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200, blank=True)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapters, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    marks_contain = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    question = RichTextUploadingField()
    hint = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

# 2 type
class Science(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200, blank=True)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapters, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    marks_contain = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    question = RichTextUploadingField()
    hint = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

# 3 type
class Computer(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200, blank=True)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapters, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    marks_contain = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    question = RichTextUploadingField()
    hint = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class Exam(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject = models.ForeignKey([object.Math or object.Science or object.Computer])  # I want to do something like this
```

I know this is not possible with foreign-key but what is the way to do things like this?

Comment: Have a look at [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `ManyToMany`, but you have to create new model:

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

class Subject(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(...)
    
    def get_class(self):
        return import_string(f"app_name.models.{self.class_name}")

class Exam(...):
    ...
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, default=None, blank=True)
```

Then simply create `Subject` object for each model you want to be with `class_name` exactly as you have your subject `__class__` name, i.e. `Subject.objects.create(class_name="Math")`. Then replace `app_name` with name of your app that **models.py** is inside.

If you need real class from `Subject` class just call `subject.get_class()`, and you will get object: `<class 'app_name.models.Math'>`.

Comment: I want to store a single object of any of the models, to directly access the object because in my case admin doesn't know which object of models to show to people. It connects the whole table to the field.